# GetByUserID as a callback function (express)

Tags: javascript, express, callback, crud

A callback function is passed as an argument to another function.
In order to respect the separation of concerns, *how can I rewrite the following example as a callback*? I know that the Req,Res part is outsourced to the router.

**Userservice.js**

```
function getByUserId(req, res, next) {

  let userIDD = req.body.userID;
  User.findOne({
    userID: userIDD
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: " + err)
    } else {

      console.log("Awesome.");
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
}
```

**UserRoute.js**

```
router.post('/publicUser/getByUserID', userService.getByUserId)
```

Comment: The `getByUserId` function looks good, what problem are you encountering?

Comment: the getByUserId function is alright, but I want to comply with the seperation of concerns. So I want to rewrite the `getByUserID` as a callback function. How does that look like ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good now but if you want to use callback and use this function as a middleware you can do `next(result)` instead of  `res.send(result)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a callback function directly in your `post` method you can use an arrow function:

```
router.post('/publicUser/getByUserID', (req, res) => {
  let userIDD = req.body.userID;
  User.findOne({
    userID: userIDD
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: " + err)
      return res.send(err);
    } 

    console.log("Awesome.");
    res.send(result)
  })
})
```